# fatal error on git push heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ssh

I'm getting error on trying to deploy my rails 4 project on Heroku.
whenever I try `git push Heroku master` command I get this error,

```
C:\Sites\projects\eventstream>git push heroku master
ssh: heroku.com: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried to check for typo errors with,

```
C:\Sites\projects\eventstream>git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:boiling-river-3096.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:boiling-river-3096.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:nileshlg2003/eventstream.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:nileshlg2003/eventstream.git (push)
```

It is same on heroku.com 
I don't know how to solve it, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you done `heroku keys:add`

Comment: yes I have added the key

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

First you check did you create properly heroku

```
heroku create boiling-river-309
```

and then

```
git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:boiling-river-3096.git
```

more info follow this

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I tried it but the result is same, 'C:\Sites\projects\eventstream>heroku create boiling-river-309
Creating boiling-river-309... done, stack is cedar
http://boiling-river-309.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:boiling-river-309.git
Git remote heroku added

C:\Sites\projects\eventstream>git remote set-url heroku git@heroku.com:boiling-r
iver-3096.git

C:\Sites\projects\eventstream>git push heroku master
ssh: heroku.com: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.'